# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'todos' before initialization App, react js

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Getting the error 'ReferenceError: Cannot access 'todos' before initialization' on useEffect

```
function App() {
    //use effect
    useEffect(() =>{
        filterHandler();
    },[todos, status]); 


    //input text
    const [inputText,setInputText]=useState('');

    //todo list
    const[todos , setTodos] = useState([]);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header>
            <h1>Todo List</h1>
            </header>
            <Form 
                todos={todos} 
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using todos near the top of your component, but you don't create the variable until lower in the component. You will need to swap the order, so that you create it first, and use it after.

```
function App() {
  //todo list
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  //use effect
  useEffect(() => {
    filterHandler();
  }, [todos, status]);

  //input text
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
      </header>
      <Form todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}
```